# Number Theory Proof Need Logic Checked

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on the following problem:

> Show that if $x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p}$, then $p \space | \space (x + y -z)$

So far my proof looks something like this:

Suppose $p \nmid \space (x+y-z)$ then $x^p + y^p = z^p$ shouldn't have a solution (proof by contraposition). Taking the original equation $\bmod p$ we have 
$$x^p + y^p = z^p \quad \rightarrow \quad x + y \equiv z \space \bmod p \quad \rightarrow \quad x + y - z \equiv 0 \space \bmod p \quad \rightarrow \quad p \mid (x + y -z)$$ (which we know is false). Hence the original equation holds.

So I don't think my logic is making sense, and am need of assistance if it's wrong. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you had the proof. By Fermat's theorem, we have $x^p\equiv x\pmod{p}$, with similar stuff for $y^p$ and $z^p$. Thus, as you wrote, if $x^p+y^p=z^p$, then $x+y\equiv z\pmod{p}$. Now **it's over**. For $x+y\equiv z\pmod{p}$ says that $p$ divides $x+y-z$. You may be letting use of logical symbols, and terms like "proof by contradiction" get in the way.

Comment: (Continued) Direct is best, it has a more concrete feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Fermat's little theorem states that $x^p \equiv x \pmod p$.

I'm not exactly certain how you want us to respond. It appears that you have the idea. The way that I would express it is as follows:

$x + y \equiv x^p + y^p = z^p \equiv z \pmod{p}$, hence $p \mid x+y -z$.

---

So, most of you know FLT as "If $x \neq 0 \pmod{p}$, then $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. The first line is a direct corollary of this result.

If $x \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then $x \equiv 0 \equiv x^p \pmod{p}$. Otheriwse, $x^p \equiv x^{p-1} x \equiv x \pmod{p}$.
Hence, in all cases, $x^p \equiv p \pmod{p}$.

Comment: I guess I'm unsure of whether if something works $mod \space p$ then it works in the general case. It's obvious that it works $mod \space p$, which is why I thought I needed to use the contrapositive. Is this incorrect?

Comment: What you are saying is essentially correct, but extremely roundabout. I expressed the same statements (in the last line), and is direct / clear about how we obtained it.

Comment: Small but important typo in the first line :).

Comment: Fermat's little theorem states that $x^p\equiv x\bmod p$ ?

Comment: I think Fermat's little theorem states: $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \space mod \space p$ where $p \nmid x$ and $p$ is prime

Comment: @Math_Illiterate  Thanks Erick. Yes, $x^p \equiv x \pmod{p}$ is an obvious consequence of FLT, and sometimes known as FLT too.